# It's a good idea to use google fusion tables as database?

Tags: php, database, google-fusion-tables

In my association we have a database site to manage various aspects of our work.

We have datasets that go from small to huge, like our members database, with ~8000 members per year. We were thinking that it could be a good idea to use google fusion tables instead of our host database to store this kind of big data.

What do you think about it? is it a reliable system? Are there rows number limitations? In average, due to google servers power, is it going to be faster than our Dreamhost database?

PS: We use wordpress as platform.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't get why it got closed, it seems a proper question to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're worried about storage or bandwidth you'd be better off upgrading your server i.e. going to dedicated platform etc.

Google Fusion Tables is good for stats and comparing data with other people in the cloud. It's definitely not the place to store sensitive member information.

Plus if you use this as your primary database Google owns it and has the ability to shut it down anytime or read from it.

Just something to think about.

Comment: Can ever a middle end database reach google infrastructures speed and bandwidth?

Comment: There are so many factors to consider. How the app or site is built, number of requests, the platform. That's some of the application layer items to consider.  On the infrastructure side, what's your server running OS wise, how much ram, storage, how's it configured,  is it a shared virtual , virtual dedicated, or dedicated server.  All these factors play into performance.  It's easy to see something Google offers and get googly eyed, but you need to take a closer look at the details.